# Android Java - Using DocumentBuilder to parse() a res/layout xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, file, android-layout

TL;DR: why doesn't

```
    File rewardFile = new File("res/layout/reward_cards.xml");
```

Work in Android Studio?

I'm having trouble referencing a res/layout file in Android Studio to get a DocumentBuilder Document instance to parse it.

What I'm trying to do is generate a variable amount of CardView objects at the bottom of a RelativeLayout object.

My current setup involves inflating the CardView object from a separate layout file, and adding it to an existing RelativeLayout view. Then, modifying the CardView XML to represent the next CardView to be added, and re-inflating from the layout file.

```
private void generateRewards(Context context, RelativeLayout mainRL) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View rewardLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reward_cards, null, false);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mainRL.findViewById(R.id.cardFutureGoals).getId()); //This is the current bottom view

    mainRL.addView(rewardLayout, rParams);

    //Now to edit the XML

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    try {
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File rewardFile = new File("res/layout/reward_cards.xml");

    Document rewardDoc = null;
    if(rewardFile.exists()) {  //This Fails
        try {
            rewardDoc = docBuilder.parse(rewardFile);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Just changing the CardView's id for now

    Node rootCard = null;
    rootCard = rewardDoc.getFirstChild();
    NamedNodeMap attr = rootCard.getAttributes();
    Node rewardId = attr.getNamedItem("id");
    rewardId.setTextContent("@+id/reward2");

    Transformer t = null;
    try {
        t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(rewardDoc);
    StreamResult s = new StreamResult("res/layout/reward_cards.xml"); //This will probably also fail
    try {
        t.transform(domSource, s);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ...

    //Inflate again and add the next cardview

    rewardLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reward_cards, null, false);

    rParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mainRL.findViewById(R.id.reward1).getId());

    mainRL.addView(rewardLayout, rParams);
}
```

And here is my reward_cards.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/reward1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.30"
    android:background="#00CF98"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

So adding the next CardView will eventually be put in a loop, but I'm just trying to get the

```
File rewardFile = new File("res/layout/reward_cards.xml");
```

To work at this point.

How do I reference the reward_cards layout file here?

Is there a much easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Will this method even work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TL;DR: why doesn't `File rewardFile = new File("res/layout/reward_cards.xml");` Work in Android Studio?

Because a resource is a file only on your development machine. It is not a file on the device.

> Then, modifying the CardView XML to represent the next CardView to be added, and re-inflating from the layout file.

You cannot modify resources at runtime.

> Will this method even work?

No.

> Is there a much easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Step #1: Inflate the layout.

Step #2: Call methods on the `CardView` and its contents to change it as you see fit.

Step #3: Add the modified `CardView` to the `RelativeLayout`.

Step #4: Lather, rinse, repeat.

If you are going to have many such `CardView` containers, consider using a `RecyclerView` or `ListView` instead of a `RelativeLayout`.